# sass complie error saying $color: null is not a color even though i declared color

Tags: css, sass

I am new to sass and I wrote some sass code but it is not compiling.

```
 $classes : primary secondary success warning danger;
    $colors : (primary:#007bff,secondary : #6c757d,success: #28a745,warning: #ffc107,dangaer: #dc3545);
    @each $class in $classes{
      .btn-#{$class}{
        $currentColor: map-get($colors,#{$class});
        background:linear-gradient(to right,$currentColor,lighten($currentColor,10%));
      }
    }
```

The error is :

```
$color: null is not a color.
stdin 14:55  root stylesheet on line 14 at column 55
```

But when I replace linear-gradient with variable it is working fine i.e

```
$classes : primary secondary success warning danger;
$colors : (primary:#007bff,secondary : #6c757d,success: #28a745,warning: #ffc107,dangaer: #dc3545);

    @each $class in $classes{
      .btn-#{$class}{
        $currentColor: map-get($colors,#{$class});
        background:$currentColor;
        //background:linear-gradient(to right,$currentColor,lighten($currentColor,10%));
      }
    }
```

This is code is compiled successfully.

What is the for nor working of $currentColor variable inside linear-gradient() function

Comment: Yeah, weird. Note that if you manually replace one of the `$currentColor` instances in your linear gradient - it works OK.

Comment: @dwjohnston yeah! It is working if I remove the $currentColor inside lighten() function Loll. I think the issue is something related to scope (Am I correct?)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed there is something with passing variables from map-get to other sass functions.

But you can slightly modify your code and it will work:

```
$classes: primary secondary success warning danger;
$colors: (
    primary: ( normal: #007bff, light: lighten(#007bff,10%) ),
    secondary: ( normal: #6c757d, light: lighten(#6c757d,10%) ),
    success: ( normal: #28a745, light: lighten(#28a745,10%) ),
    warning: ( normal: #ffc107, light: lighten(#ffc107,10%) ),
    danger: ( normal: #dc3545, light: lighten(#dc3545,10%) )
);
@each $class in $classes{
  .btn-#{$class}{
    $currentColor: map-get(map-get($colors,#{$class}), normal);
    $currentColorLighten: map-get(map-get($colors,#{$class}), light);

    background: linear-gradient(to right, $currentColor, $currentColorLighten);
  }
}
```

You define two colors for each class (normal and lighten version) and just use it via double map-get.